# HTML5 / JS storage event handler

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm using Safari webkit's engine together with HTML5 and JS to create an offline application now I'm using the `sessionStorage` array to store status of my application(simulation).

The storage data works fine with the inspector the functions work fine it's the event handler that isn't responding.

The test preformd by `Anurag` at http://jsfiddle.net/pvRgH/ also doesn't work here:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', storageEventHandler, false);
function storageEventHandler(evt){
    alert("storage event called key: " + evt.key );
    switch(evt.key){
        case 'bat1':
        case 'bat2': batteryDCMeter(); break;
        case 'extPowerOn': rechargeBattery(); break;
    }   
}

function load()
{
    dashcode.setupParts();
    //set HTML 5 key/value's
    sessionStorage.setItem('bat1', 'OFF');
    sessionStorage.setItem('bat2', 'OFF');
    sessionStorage.setItem('bat1DC', '26.2');
    sessionStorage.setItem('bat2DC', '26.2');
}

function bat1OnOff(event)
{
    if(sessionStorage['bat1'] == 'OFF'){
        sessionStorage['bat1'] = 'ON';
    }else{
        sessionStorage['bat1'] = "OFF";
    }
}


function bat2OnOff(event)
{
    if(sessionStorage['bat2'] == 'OFF'){
        sessionStorage['bat2'] = 'ON';
    }else{
        sessionStorage['bat2'] = "OFF";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Storage event handlers only fire if the storage event is triggered from another window.

[How can I get an event to fire every time localStorage is updated in Safari 5+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562929/how-can-i-get-an-event-to-fire-every-time-localstorage-is-updated-in-safari-5)

Answer (score 1):

the 'storage' event occurred by the other tab in the browser. When you change the storage in one page and addEventLister also in this page , the window can not catch the message.

for example

You have two page,
pageOne change the storage , pageTwo will catch the 'storage' message and handle this, but pageOne couldn't catch the message.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some more code for how you are storing the keys? It works for me on Safari - http://jsfiddle.net/pvRgH/

Comment: The link you provided the code doesn't give any results. Check updated question for more code

Comment: So there's no alert popping up indicating the storage event handler was called for you? What version of Safari are you testing this on?

Comment: No nothing is happening I'm running Safari 5.0(6533.16) MacOSX 10.6.3

Comment: Nothing happens for me either (Safari 5.0.3, Chrome 10)

Answer (score 0):

**To communicate between multiple tabs we can use storage event**. You store a data item in local storage and you will get to know that your local storage is updated.

Check out the code.

```js
      window.addEventListener("storage", storageEventHandler, false);

      function storageEventHandler(evt) {
        alert("storage updated");
      }

      function clickme() {
        localStorage.setItem("someKey", "someValue");
      }
```

```html
<button onclick="clickme()">Click Me</button>
```

**Note: storage event only fires in other tabs. Not inside the tab, you are in currently. click^ :)**