# Is Local Storage Persistant?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm using Local Storage for a Chrome extensions. When I set the local storage using

```
localStorage['tracking'] = false;
```

... and then check to is local storage set using:

```
if(localStorage['tracking'])
{
    alert('set');
} else {
    alert('Not Set');
    localStorage['tracking'] = true;
}
```

It works fine. It sets tracking to true if unset and remains set. But if I go to a new tab, and to the same page I was on in the other tab, it returns unset.

Is there any way for local storage to remain persistant, even after the browser has closed?

Edit: I am not setting the localStorage array element at the top if the script. Just realised that might confuse readers.

Comment: The whole idea of local storage is that it is persistent. But there is dedicated local storage for every domain. So maybe two different tabs (I mean empty, because not empty with different addresses of course are not) are recognized as different domains and that's why they don't share data.

Comment: I am using the same domain (Google.com) when testing.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
localStorage.setItem('tracking', false);
```

and

```
localStorage.getItem('tracking');
```

These are the methods used in the [W3C API Specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/).

Since the usage you mentioned is not specified, depending on browser implementation it is possible that you are adding new properties to the `localStorage` global variable in the current `window` object, which become unavailable when navigating away from the page.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage works only with strings. Check [this](http://blog.yjl.im/2010/05/localstorage-primitive-types-and-json.html) explanation.

Comment: I see. But, why does it still work? If I check the data in the localStorage I can see tracking is set to true. Maybe Chrome have implemented localStorage to allow for booleans?

Comment: `true` is stored as `"true"`. That evaluates to `true` when put in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem. I would like to share my solution. However, my case may not be the same as your case.

My case ist that I had this code (localStrage['xxxx']='xxx';) in a content script. Then I had the problem when open the new tab or open new windows.

So, my solution is that I did not run this code by the content script directly. The content script will call 'chrome.extension.sendRequest' and the background.html will do set/read localStrage and return to the content script.

This will be the code in content script

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({action: 'load'}, function (response) {
            if(response){
                  alert('set');
            } else {
                  alert('Not Set');
                  chrome.extension.sendRequest({action: 'set',value:'true'}, function (response) {});
            }
}
```

This will be the code in background.html.

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == 'load') {
        sendResponse(localStorage['tracking']);

            }else if (request.action == 'set') {
                localStorage['tracking']=request.value;
            }
     });
```